# Git permission denied (public key) error

Tags: ssh, git

I have connected many times to github and know about generating ssh keys and putting the `id_rsa.pub` into github settings.  But for some reason with this install I can not get it to connect.  I am just trying to clone a private repo to a new server but when I the clone I get :

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

If I run :

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

It tells me I have successfully authenticated.

What else can I try?  I am running this on a bitnami stack so maybe that is causing issues?  This is probably the problem, I just am not sure what to do about it.  There are already a set of keys in the .ssh/authorized_keys dir.  I left those alone as this is how I am connecting with putty/pagent.  I put the new keys in /.ssh and left the authorized_keys alone.  What would be the correct way to set this up?  Should I just delete both pairs and start over?  Use the same keys for putty and github?  Why do I still authenticate if there is a problem?

Comment: are you trying to connect from Windows or Linux? I'm confused by your below comment & your mention of putty here

Comment: Hi sorry it is confusing.  I am connecting from Windows to the bitnami server with Putty.  The bitnami server itself is running Linux.  I am trying to connect to github from the Linux server.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new SSH certificate, i.e. key pair?

1 Generate default key pair:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "defaultuser@gmail.com"
```

Don't use this if you already have an SSH certificate.

2 Generate additional key pairs:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "seconduser@gmail.com"
```

3 Add non-default keys

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_seconduser
Enter passphrase for /Users/defaultuser/.ssh/id_rsa_seconduser: 
Identity added: /Users/defaultuser/.ssh/id_rsa_defaultuser  (/Users/defaultuser/.ssh/id_rsa_defaultuser)
```

4 Set SSH configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`) so SSH knows which key to be used for which server:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/XXXUser/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-client
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/XXXUser/.ssh/id_rsa_XXXSECONDUSER
```

5 Make sure in the `.git/config` file for the Git project associated with the second user account at Github that you are using correct host name `github-client` but not `github.com`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github-client:foobarsomeuser/foobar.git
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped me figure out what to do.  The problem was that I was trying to use the default bitnami user.  I generated the keys as a new user and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your public key is either missing or you've placed an incorrect public key in your keyring. Check if the keyring exists in `~/.ssh`. Hard to say without mentioning your OS

---

> There are already a set of keys in the .ssh/authorized_keys dir.

I believe these are the keys required to ssh into the Linux server.

Best way would be to regenerate a new set of private/public keys for github, add the PK to your Linux server keyring and paste the public key over at [Github accounts](https://github.com/account/ssh).

Comment: I updated my question to try and explain better.  Yes the keys are in ~/.ssh (and another set in authorized_keys).  This stack is Linux 64bit I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand though.  I keep the keys that are there to ssh into the server and create a new set for github?  What does it mean to add to the keyring?  Do I put it in the .pem I downloaded when setting up the AMI?  Please a bit more details.

Comment: @zac Computist [has explained](http://superuser.com/a/380791/4377) what I meant

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `gnome-keyring-daemon` under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753293/1156933